# Wso2 5.3 : Source code for authenticationendpoint war and other wars

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am on **wso2 5.3 version**, and need to customize the following wars for project need.

- oauth2.war
- accountrecoveryendpoint.war
- emailotpauthenticationendpoint.war
- authenticationendpoint

Could you please share the github repo url for these wars which are deployed under :
{wso2Home}\repository\deployment\server\webapps folder

Could you please share the steps needed to build/compile the authenticationendpoint.war after making changes ?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the sources at the following repositories/locations

[Oauth](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/tree/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint)

[accountrecoveryendpoint](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/tree/v5.7.5/components/identity-mgt/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint)

[emailotpauthenticationendpoint](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-email-otp/tree/master/component/authentication-endpoint)

[authenticationendpoint](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/tree/v5.7.5/components/authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint)

They all can be build with the usual maven commands (`mvn clean install`). Just make sure you delete any extracted webapp folders of those when replacing with your custom built ones. Otherwise the new webapps won't be deployed.

Comment: I am getting `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP` when trying to authenticationendpoint run on Tomcat. Do I need to specify something else?